# How to refresh cluster access-token in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have three clusters in `Google Kubernetes Engine`, and I am trying to see Kubernetes dashboard but I get the same `access-token` for two different clusters.

Using `kubectl config view` command I get:

```
- name: gke_PROJECT_ZONE_A_NAME_A
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: TOKEN-A

- name: gke_PROJECT_ZONE_B_NAME_B
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: TOKEN-B

- name: gke_PROJECT_ZONE_C_NAME_C
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: TOKEN-B
```

when gke_PROJECT_ZONE_B_NAME_B and gke_PROJECT_ZONE_C_NAME_C share the same access token, hence when I connect via `kubectl proxy` and insert the token I get the same the dashboard.

How I can refresh the access token for cluster B or C so i'll get the desired dashboard?

i've tried to use `gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER-C --zone ZONE-C --project MY_PROJECT`, which returns

> Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data. kubeconfig entry generated
>   for CLUSTER-C.

and afterwards I don't get any access token for CLUSTER-C

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the UI service by running `kubectl proxy`, entering to the UI via `http://localhost:8001/ui` and refreshing the page cause the access token to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your access token for CLUSTER-C, you can do this

```
$ kubectl config set-credentials gke_PROJECT_ZONE_C_NAME_C --token=""
```

Comment: I didn't have access token so I couldn't connect